# How is the property in webconfig maxRequestLength measured

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I would like to increase this value

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2024000" executionTimeout="300"/>
```

But i am not sure how it is measured, MB, KB? not sure. I would like to be able to accept requests up to 50 MB.

Regards

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The property *maxRequestLength* indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET. This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks caused by users posting large files to the server. The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx)

For 50 MB you will need to set it to 51200.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300"/>
```

**Edit** based on comments

The OP does not ask about executionTimeout but @barnes did in comments below. I feel to add some details about `executionTimeout` as well which is other `httpRuntime` attribute.

[executionTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Optional TimeSpan attribute. 
>   Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute  > before being automatically shut
>   down by ASP.NET. This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in
>   the compilation element is False. To help to prevent shutting down the
>   application while you are debugging, do not set this time-out to a
>   large value. The default is "00:01:50" (110 seconds), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx) `executionTimeout="HH:MM:SS"`. What is the unit in your case?

Comment: It is in seconds, It is also in seconds from MSDN link you provided,  executionTimeout="seconds"

Comment: Means we can either provide time total number of seconds or in "HH:MM:SS" format. Thanks

Comment: Yes, example is given in the MSDN documentation, "The default is "00:01:50" (110 seconds)."

Comment: FWIW, it seems like Microsoft says kilobytes (1KB = 1,000 bytes) but everyone means kibibytes (1KiB = 1,024 bytes). And same with Megabytes (1MB = 1,000KB) vs. Mebibytes (1MiB = 1,024KiB).

Answer (score 7):

It accepts KB. For 50 MB, set it to

```
maxRequestLength="51200"
```

Answer (score 6):

`maxRequestLength` is measured in kilobytes

`maxAllowedContentLength` is measured in bytes

Comment: Yeah. I was always amazed with the genius of the architects who designed these parameters.