# HttpWebRequest copy big file and get 404 not found

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I copy without problem small file. 
When users try to upload a file of big dimension (I guess > 60MB) I got into a web Exception (404 Not Found).

I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to the file size. I got exception at

```
webRequest.GetResponse()
```

Do I need modification server side?
Any suggestion is appreciate.

```
    public static bool UploadFile(IResult result, string pathFile, Stream stream)
    {
        // upload effettivo del file su DB
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(ClientCommon.Properties.Settings.Default.FileServiceURI) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream s = null;
        try
        {
            webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            using (WebRequestBuilder wrb = new WebRequestBuilder())
            {
                webRequest.ContentType = wrb.ContentType;

                wrb.AddTextPart("cdFile", pathFile);
                wrb.AddFilePart("file", stream);
                wrb.AddTextPart("destination", pathFile);


                if (wrb.GetContent(result, out s) == false)
                    return false;

                s.CopyTo(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
            }

            response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException exc)
        {
            result.SetError(exc.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();

            if (s != null)
                // When the above code has ended, close the streams
                s.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the server have a request size limit?

Comment: which application are you using `WebAPI`, `WebAPI Core` and else?

Comment: try to set attribute `maxRequestLength="2147483647"` in `httpRuntime` inside `system.web` in your `web.config`

Comment: @ershoaib It seems not working

Comment: @Richard I have issues both on IIS Express and on deployed app

Comment: try to add this => `<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>` inside `<system.webServer>` and let me know

Comment: and keep this also => `maxRequestLength="2147483647"` in `httpRuntime` inside `system.web` in your web.config

Comment: by above code you can receive file upto 2GB length. you may modify it by yours need

Comment: @ershoaib Perfect! Only the tag security solved my issue! Thanks a lot. Put it as answer if you want ;)

Comment: yes sure glad to hear, I add this as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below code in your `web.config`.

```
<system.web>
     <!-- Your other settings here -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="Your Framework" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <!-- Your other settings here -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**maxRequestLength:** The property maxRequestLength indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET. This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks caused by users posting large files to the server. The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438332/5514820) you can read more about `maxRequestLength`.

**maxAllowedContentLength:** Specifies limits on requests processed by the Web server. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022517/5514820) you can read more about `maxAllowedContentLength`.

By above code you can receive file upto 2GB length. you may modify it by yours need