# How to limit Blazor Server Side request size

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently making an application in Blazor Server Side.
I am afraid of one thing, in the following component:

```
<input @bind="Text"/>

@code{
    string Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Say if some attacker were to paste a 1GB string in the input, how could I prevent the payload from reaching the server?

Blazor Server side uses signalR so maybe there is a way that I don't know of to limit the total transfer size

Comment: Maybe settings MaxRequestLength in the web.config where the request is send to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438317/how-is-the-property-in-webconfig-maxrequestlength-measured

Comment: @VDWWD there is no web.config in blazor, at least that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data annotation to your property such as `[StringLength(255)]`.